# Virtualbox: host only networking - proxy internet connection

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I'll ask my question first, then give details about where I am coming from:

Is it possible to use host only, then have host (Ubuntu) act as a proxy to provide internet access to the guest (Windows)? If so, how?

I am trying to get the right combination of networking for my VirtualBox Windows client VM (Windows 7).  My host is Wbuntu 10.10 (Maverick).

I believe I understand the basic network options (please correct me if I am incorrect):

*NAT -* Host can't communicate with guest but guest has access to all host's adapters

*Host only* - Separate adapter but guest has no net access

*Bridged* - bridge an adapter in the host with the virtual adapter to give the host access to the host adapter

I am trying to give my win guest internet access, but also access the host in a separate network.

Bridged only works when the host is connected to the internet (this is a laptop) so when it's not connected the network is down.

Thanks I appreciate your help.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to access the VM from another machine?

Comment: I want the best of both worlds - I want my guest to have access to the internet, and I want a network connection between guest/host.  The only way I could see this happening is connecting the host to the guest, then have a proxy server setup on the host to provide internet access to the guest.

Comment: Bridging actually puts the VM on the network so it will work almost like a completely separate computer when it comes to networking. What about 2 virtual network adapters?

Comment: @Reuben - yeah, but when the network is disconnected (eg laptop out of the office), there is no longer a connection between the host and guest on the laptop.

Comment: Since then, I have done this quite simply - I enable two network adapters, one using NAT for internet, and one for host only.  Works great!

Comment: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38822/8555

Comment: Bridged - bridge an adapter in the host with the virtual adapter to give the *guest (not host)* access to the host adapter

Answer (score 4):

Ok well I finally got it working.

I have installed the Squid proxy server on my Ubuntu host, and added the virtualbox adapter.

This link was very useful for quickly getting squid running:
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-setup-transparent-squid-proxy-server-in-ubuntu.html

All I need to do now is fix a little issue I am having with the vboxnet0 adapter but all good.

Answer (score 0):

Internet access in Virtualbox Host-only networking

http://jackal777.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/internet-access-in-virtualbox-host-only-networking/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up having two network adapters enabled on the guest, one NAT, one host-only.
That gives Internet access AND host access.